# ffmpeg: scaling the video without changing the actual width and height

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I want to scale a video with ffmpeg.

This is a picture of what I'm trying to achieve:

[a picture of what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMe6M.png)

I don't want the actual width and height to be affected, I just want to scale the video a little bit smaller to give a space to write something above and below it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [pad filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "pad=720:1280:-1:-1:color=magenta" -c:a copy output.mp4
```